# serverspec - can 'should_be_owned_by' check multiple owners

Tags: serverspec

I'm new to ServerSpec, Rspec, ruby so don't have much knowledge of the specifics of the grammar available. I'd like to write a test that does something like:

```
describe file("foo") do
    it { should_be_owned_by 'bill' or 'ted' }
end
```

That test runs but seems to only check the first owner and not the second.

Is there a standard way to perform a test where there may be multiple acceptable values?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can not find it in [the official `file` documentation](http://serverspec.org/resource_types.html#file), but you can use a *grep* regular expression pattern there:

```ruby
describe file('foo') do
  it { should_be_owned_by 'bill\|ted' }
end
```

Since RSpec `3.0` you can also use [`.or` to make compound expectations](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-4/docs/compound-expectations#use-%60or%60-to-chain-expectations):

```ruby
describe file('foo') do
  it { should be_owned_by('bill').or be_owned_by('ted') }
end
```